# Node MongoDB driver: can't findOne by integer id with the driver but can with mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have problems querying a document by id with `findOne()`. The documents are written to `shorts` collection with a custom automatically incremented integer id. The resulting documents have format as e.g.
`{ "_id": 13, "fullURL": "google.com" }`. When I'm trying to query a document from the collection it returns `null`:

```js
// call queryUrlById(db, 13)
const queryUrlById = (db, id) => { 

  console.log(`searching id: ${id}`);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection('shorts')
      .findOne({ _id: id })
      .then(found => {
        console.log(`Found: ${found}`);
        db.close();
        resolve(found.fullURL);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        db.close();
        reject(err);
      })
  });
};

// In console:
// searching id: 13
// Found: null
```

At the same time, an identical command in mongo `shell` works just fine:

```
> db.shorts.findOne({_id: 13})
{ "_id" : 13, "fullURL" : "google.com" }
```

***What I've tried so far:***

1. Rewrite `findOne()` with a callback
2. Change the query to `{"_id": id}`

None of which worked out as expected.

Comment: My guess is that `id` is a string, not an integer. So you should try casting it to one.

Comment: Agree with @str. Try JSON.parse on id

Comment: @str of course! Let me test it and if it works I'll accept it as the answer

Comment: @Jesper Don't `JSON.parse` but `parseInt` for casting.

Comment: @str Hmm, what's the difference?

Comment: @Jesper The result is the same, but the semantics are not. If you want to parse a JSON string, use `JSON.parse`, if you want to cast a string to an integer, use `parseInt`.

Comment: @str didn't know that! Do you know why it is like that? For better clarification of the parsed data, or does it have some kind of functional improvement?

Answer (score 1):

If you mongodb package installed,you can run the query using the below 2 lines

```
var mongo=require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var ObjectID=require("mongodb").ObjectId;
```

The syntax of the findOne function should be as follows:

```
db.collection("shorts").findOne({_id:ObjectID(id)});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is not the case here because the `_id` value is custom.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` in the query required casting from String to Number.

@str was first to post the solution. Thanks to everyone!